# anonymous/ https option is not visible in gerrit after upgrade to 2.14.1 from 2.11.7

Tags: gerrit

I have upgraded gerrit from version 2.11.5 to 2.14.1 , and I cant see anonymous http and https tab anymore to clone my repositories (only http and ssh urls are present) . Also, I am not able to clone using http url which gives me 401, even though i am using right password.

For login I can see password doesnot match error in logs (which isnt true) .I am using right password .

Also, my log file is full of below warnings

```
[2017-07-31 09:35:18,326] [sshd-SshServer[5d8319a7]-nio2-thread-5] WARN  org.apache.sshd.server.session.ServerSessionI
mpl : exceptionCaught(ServerSessionImpl[null@/xx.xx.xx.xxx:38772])[state=Opened] IOException: Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some itens to check:

1) Make sure the [donwloads-commands plugin](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-plugins.html#download-commands) is installed and running without issues

- Check Plugins > installed
- Check GERRIT-SITE/plugins
- Restart Gerrit and check GERRIT-SITE/logs/error_log

2) Make sure you have set the [download options](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#download) in GERRIT-SITE/etc/gerrit.config

```
[download]
    scheme = anon_http
    scheme = http
    scheme = ssh
```

Comment: there is no such option as "scheme = https"

Comment: Sorry... I fixed the download options. Did this solve the anonymous issue? Check your gerrit.canonicalWebUrl option too.

Comment: We have not had this value set before in gerrit 2.11.7 version ...not sure if it has been introduced in later versions .

Comment: Which value? I saw the 2.11.7 documentation and the download options (anon_http, http and ssh) are there. Maybe the download-commands plugin changed in some way.

Comment: I can in gerrit version 2.14.1 "HTTP Digest Authentication Removed" ...what does that mean? Any idea how it can impact application "

Comment: I'm not sure if I can explain this correctly... These are some info related: 1) https://www.gerritcodereview.com/releases/2.14.md#HTTP-Digest-Authentication-Removed 2) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication